# Reduction of size in diatoms due to asexual reproduction

Tags: reproduction

From [this](http://www.mbari.org/staff/conn/botany/phytoplankton/phytoplankton_diatom_asexual.HTM) we can see that diatoms reduce their size after asexual reproduction.[image]

This would ultimately lead to nonviable small size. Is there any mechanism to avoid this ?

Comment: Oh at last... someone used the "answer your own question" option! Anyway, a related [This](http://people.westminstercollege.edu/faculty/tharrison/emigration/diatoms.htm),[this](http://www.int-res.com/articles/meps/30/m030p093.pdf) and [this one](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15380667) are related articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The ability to reproduce sexually is closely associated with cell size
>   of the diatom. It is the most prevalent method of restoring cell size,
>   and it is often triggered when the size of a cell is less than a
>   critical level (usually smaller than half of the original size for
>   most species).

Source : [Sexual reproduction in diatoms](http://wgbis.ces.iisc.ernet.in/biodiversity/sahyadri_enews/newsletter/issue26/article1/chap4.htm)